# How to Enable DEBUG log level in Spring MVC 4

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, logging, log4j

I have a simple spring MCV application (spring-webmvc 5.0.6) and when running I can see the logs are printing.

My question is how to enable Debug log level. Currently I haven't add and log4j property file but I can see the logs are printing in INFO level.

I tried to find answers to this simple question, so far was not able.

My pom.xml file dependency section has following dependencies.

```
spring-webmvc (5.0.6.RELEASE)
servlet-api (2.5)
jstl (1.2)
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said that you didn´t provide a logging-implementation, Springs variant of Commons Logging API will only find Java.util.logging (JUL) from the JDK (see [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/apache/commons/logging/package-summary.html))

By the way: Level.DEBUG in Terms of JUL would be Level.FINE or Level.FINER (see this Articel [Log Levels)](https://blog.takipi.com/is-standard-java-logging-dead-log4j-vs-log4j2-vs-logback-vs-java-util-logging/)

Assuming that your app is running on a Tomcat-Server you might edit one of the following files to see Level.FINE on the Console:

Just add:

`java.util.ConsoleHandler.level=FINE
 org.springframework.level=FINE`

1. **${java.home}/lib/logging.properties**  (global loggin-properties of JRE)
2. **${catalina.base}/conf/logging.properties** (global logging-properties of Tomcat)
3. **WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties** (webapp-specific logging-properties)